# Statistical Hash Function and Cryptographic together

Tags: hash, cryptography

How about the combination? Say Statistical Hash Function h1 and Cryptographic hash function h2.

Now we have h1(h2(x)) and h2(h1(x)). Which among the two are better and why?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? What do you mean by "better?"

Comment: What's a statistical hash? And why do you want to combine one with a crypto hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Layering hash functions will produce a result that has collision resistance as weak as the weakest of the used hash functions. Without specific knowledge of the desired security results, layering hash functions like this is generally [not good practice](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/270/593) if your goal is to improve security.

Comment: It's tricky to tell the strength of hashfunction combiners. Depending on the properties you care about and a few reasonable assumptions about the weaker one, it can be as strong as the stronger.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Indeed. I didn't include the qualifications/details. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of collision resistance, h1(h2(h3(...(x))) is no better than the worst of the individual hash functions. For example, if h2(x)=0 regardless of x, h1(h2(h3(...(x))) will give the same hash regardless of x as well.

In terms of performance, h1(h2(h3(...(x))) is worse than the worst of the individual hash functions, for obvious reasons.

I know I'm not answering your question, but why do you want the the combination?